# Text in string is name of another string

Tags: javascript

So I have array with some names. And names are other strings. Look at my code and you will know what I am trying to do. I don't wanna use array in array and switch.

```
var str = ["jun", "ede", "sin", "ddw"];
var jun = ["jun1", "jun2"];
var ede = ["ede1", "ede2"];
showValue(str[1]);
function showValue(name) {
  return name[0];
}
```

I want to return "ede1". How I can do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript

Comment: You can create sub-arrays before main array like this: `var jun = ["jun1", "jun2"]; var str = [jun, ede, sin, ddw];` Where "jun" is array

Answer (score 1):

According to what you are trying to achieve:

```
 var jun = ["jun1", "jun2"];
 var ede = ["ede1", "ede2"];
 var str = [jun, ede, "sin", "ddw"];

/* Here "ede" and ede are different. "ede" is a string and ede is a variable */


showValue(str[1]);  // str[1] is ede

function showValue(name) {
     console.log(name[0]); // ede[0] is "ede1"
 }
```

Console displaying `ede1`.

You have to pass those variables in `str` array.

This is one way of doing it and easier way to do it unless you understand the window object that is the global object of javascript.

Comment: Yes, it is simplest way. Check my comment =)

Comment: Oh, I didn't check. haha. He passed the string instead of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var str = ["jun", "ede", "sin", "ddw"];
var jun = ["jun1", "jun2"];
var ede = ["ede1", "ede2"];
showValue(str[1]);
// => "ede1"

function showValue(name) {
  return window[name][0];
}
```